# internationalisation in android

Tags: android, internationalization

I am making an app in which I want to implement internationalization. 
I have created alternative resources like

res/values-fr/strings.xml 
 which Contains French text for all the strings, including title

Can anyone tell me what to do next...

thanks

Comment: There is just too much to tell. Externalizing resources (texts, graphics, sounds, etc.) is one thing, proper formatting of dates, times, numbers, etc. is another. To make matter worse this is just the beginning but the topic is too broad to be answered in one question, besides it would be just off-topic (no programming is involved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always have default strings in `res/values/strings.xml`, because Android tries to use the most specific resource available. If you have for example `res/values-fr/strings.xml` and `res/values-de/strings.xml` and the users phone is set to English, your app will crash because neither `de` nor `fr`  are applicable for English there are no fallback resources.

After you have specified your default strings and any translations in their respective subfolders, you can use the strings by their qualifiers. For example `R.string.some_string`. Android will then use the most appropriate translation that is available for the users current device language.

All that and more is explained here: [Localizing with Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: So what problems are you facing? Be more specific.

Comment: DO I need to change the language of device for testing by going through        Home > Menu > Settings > Locale & text > Select locale

Comment: Yes. Android checks if there is a recourse with the corresponding language-qualifier (e.g. `en` for English) and uses it. If there is no file for the current language, the normal files without any qualifier are used.

Answer (score 0):

Device will load locale automatically based on system languge. No extra steps required unless you want to change locale in your app independently.

Comment: and how to change the locale of app

Comment: @ekiyot: You do not need to change "locale of an app". Sometimes you need to detect it (`Locale.getDefault()`) and that's it. Please do not implement language selecting in your app, this is common anti-pattern (user already selected his/her language for entire OS).

Comment: @PawełDyda that is a very bad idea, because: I am using EN for OS level, most of apps are in EN. If from settings there is a language selector and I want to see that app in other language than I will select it, but I don't want for the whole OS, for sure

Comment: @matheszabi I have no idea what you're referring to, but it seems that you're "Language switcher" kind of guy. OK, maybe you need one specific app in different language. How many users out there are like you? How many users will ___know___ how to change the language? And what language switcher is for? Besides, if you force me to select language, I am not using your app. Ever. No matter what it does.  I already said what language I prefer. Of course you can give a choice to that 0.001% of users that want this 1 app in different language, but for God's sake make OS language the default one.

Comment: @PawełDyda around me 99% preffer methods presented above. Highly disagree with Samsung market too: he is selecting the language based on location. He doesn't care if I don't know that language what I am right now. Software language is English, if you can find you mother language, which is not English, than is good. I will not limit myself to a Windows or any other OS in my language and have android app 1% because I do prefer that one. Give me the English, because you have and an option to select a language, if you have. This is the main problem in Germany, Hungary why people doesn't speak En