# Get TextView string ID from R.string

Tags: android, string, textview

I want to find out the integer value associated to a string into the R.string file, from the TextView control that displays it.

So, I have a TextView called MyTextView and I associated it's string as this

```
MyTextView.setText(R.string.MyString);
```

Now, what I want is to create some function that gives me the string ID of MyTextView, something like *GetStringId(MyTextView)*. Maybe the TextView package already has this implemented and I cannot find it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, your `GetStringId(MyTextView)`-method would return `R.string.MyString` (or the associated integer) in your case?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be easy to archive, for what purpose do you need it?

Comment: I have my strings divided into two languages group: English and Spanish. English strings start with "en_", Spanish ones start with "es_". When a button is pressed I wanna change everything on the layout from English to Spanish by changing the string name's prefix. For example "en_englishtext" should be changed to "es_spanish". I could replace the "en_" by "es_" but in order to do that I need the string id, get the string value, replace, find it in R.strings and apply it.

Comment: And this is about making the application "multilingual"?

Comment: Well, maybe there's a better way of doing this

Comment: Yeah, I found something better. Researching...

Comment: Added some information as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add multiple translations to your application, you should use the "language-qualified-resources", as explained on the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Basically, you add your strings for the fallback-language (which is often English), to your `res/values/strings.xml`-file.

Any other translations (e.g. for Spanish) go into their language-qualified-resource directory with the given language-qualifier (specified in [ISO 639-1](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php)). For Spanish, this would be `res/values-es/strings.xml`.

Android then checks the current device-language, searches for any translations with the corresponding language-qualifier, and automatically uses the strings specified in that file. If it can't find any folder with a corresponding language-qualifier, it uses the one without a qualifier (e.g. the "fallback"-language).

This is a service from Android, you simply have to put the corresponding translations in the corresponding language-qualified folders and Android will do the rest for you.

Also see this older question: [internationalisation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441000/internationalisation-in-android/7441027#7441027)

Comment: Can I change the used strings.xml file programmatically?

Comment: You don't need to. If the device-language is changed, Android will do it for you.

Comment: O.K. Maybe as a desktop developer I make many mistakes by treating Android apps like desktop apps. So, there's no need to add buttons for changing the language "from inside" the application, because if users wanna do it, they have to change the language of the entire O.S.

Comment: It is (in my eyes) the kind of behavior you would expect from an application. And I'm not sure if there is any way to change the used `strings.xml`-file "in-code". Leave out the "change-language"-buttons and let Android do it for you.

Comment: One last question. Is this supported in all versions of Android?

Comment: Yes. This is a standard Android-platform feature since version 1.0 No need for fallback-stuff :D

Comment: O.K. Thanks from turning me away from the wrong path. This will save me a lot of time.

Comment: Good explanation but it doesn't answer the question. In my case for example I want to translate the app *dynamically* so after I set the locale, I would like to do something like: `textView.setText(res.getString(textView.getStringId))`

Comment: Continuation: That way I could add some generic functionality. Otherwise I have to specify in each case the string resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily implement your own function for setting text to a TextView that does what you want. Simply do something like:

```
    textview.setText(R.string.my_text);
    textview.setTag(new Integer(R.string.my_text));
```

in the function for setting the text and then in the second function (for getting the string ID) do something like this:

```
    return ((Integer)textview.getTag()).intValue();
```

Read the documentation of the following two functions:

> [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28%29)
>   [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28%29)

Comment: Yes, that could be a way of doing it.